# Where in an ASP.NET WebForms project can "System.Web.UI.Control" namespace found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Does anyone know where in an ASP WebForms project can "System.Web.UI.Control" namespace found? Where the `<asp:Hyperlink> or <asp:Hiddenfild>`are? Is it at Web.config?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Web.UI` namespace is within the `System.Web.dll` assembly.

There are multiple namespaces containing controls:

`System.Web.UI` has `Control`, `UserControl`, and `LiteralControl` (**not** the same thing as `<asp:Literal />`) and some other primitives.

`System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` has the "HTML Controls" which are representations of normal HTML elements with `runat="server"` applied, such as `<a runat="server" href="~/foo" />`.

`System.Web.UI.WebControls` contains the "Web Controls" library, which are more complex controls which (for better or for worse) force the web-developer to relinquish control (no pun intended) about how the page is rendered. These controls are referenced using ASPX syntax in the `<asp: />` element namespace. These are controls like `<asp:HyperLink` and `<asp:Login`.

Answer (score 1):

That namespace is not in the project, it's in the `System.Web.dll` library.

You can find a reference to System.Web in the `References` node in your solution.

The `HyperLink` and `HiddenField` classes will be found in the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace, and they inherit the `Control` class which you can find in the `System.Web.UI` namespace.